# Faster searching for subsets with pairwise conditions

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks, code-request, searching, tuples

I am looking for a faster way of finding large subsets of lists that obey pairwise conditions.  In particular, I'm looking for a large (over 10k) set of quaternary words (i.e. ordered lists) of length 13 with Hamming distance greater than 5.

Here's an example in code: there are 67,108,864 words with 4 letters:

```
all = Tuples[Range[4], 13];
```

A naive solution to find a set that are all at least Hamming distance 5, we can sample one-at-a-time and compare to the current set:

```
set = Internal`Bag[];
Internal`StuffBag[set, RandomChoice[all]];
Dynamic[Internal`BagLength[set], UpdateInterval -> 1]

While[Internal`BagLength @ set < 10000,
 new = RandomChoice[all];
 If[AllTrue[Internal`BagPart[set, All], 
   HammingDistance[new, #] > 5 &], Internal`StuffBag[set, new]]]

result = Internal`BagPart[set, All];
```

I'm looking to find a set of length 10,000 but at the moment this code is just too slow, after an hour it only found about 1,400.

*Can this type of random search problem be accelerated using compilation, parallelization, graph theory, heuristics, or anything else?*

**Related:**

- This is equivalent to the graph problem of finding a clique of size $n$, however it's too costly to build the underlying graph. Still maybe `FindKClique` could be useful somehow?
- For the n=4 case, R implements multicore evolutionary algorithms for [the same problem with DNA strings](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/DNABarcodes/inst/doc/DNABarcodes.html)
- Compiled hamming distance: [Fastest way to measure Hamming distance of integers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23403/fastest-way-to-measure-hamming-distance-of-integers)

Comment: Do you find the "Bag" functions to be especially faster than the `"DynamicArray"` data structure? Slightly off topic since in this question appending elements to the list is not the rate limiting step.

Comment: I can get a decent speedup over your code by just creating a `NearestFunction` at each iteration of the `While` loop and using that to find the nearest already-selected element.  But the scaling of this problem means it still slows to a crawl eventually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Might be faster to cull as you go. I compile the selection function (possibly it can be made faster). Also I set the history length to zero although that does not help too much because the `Select` entails a big memory hit at least one time.

```
$HistoryLength = 0;

selectHam = 
  Compile[{{ll, _Integer, 2}, {vec, _Integer, 1}, {n, _Integer}}, 
   Select[ll, (Min[Apply[Plus, Sign[Abs[# - vec]]]] > n) &], 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

To keep my machine from croaking I only go to 12-tuples.

```
all = Tuples[Range[4], 12];
Length[all]

(* Out[22]= 16777216 *)
```

This takes around 20 minutes:

```
j = 0;
Timing[
 res = Reap[recent = all[[1]];
     rest = Rest@all;
     Sow[recent];
     While[rest =!= {},
      PrintTemporary[{j++, Length[rest]}];
      ok = selectHamG5[rest, recent];
      Sow[recent = First[ok]];
      rest = Rest[ok]
      ];
     ][[2, 1]];]
Length[res]

(* Out[24]= {1170.45, Null}

Out[25]= 4096 *)
```

I am currently running on a bigger machine for the 13-tuples case. I expect it to take a few hours to run to completion.

One might be able to curtail the memory overhead by using `Scan` (or `Do`), `Sow` and `Reap` instead of `Select` in the culling function.

--- edit ---

For tuples of modest length this can be done faster by representing each tuple as an integer. And the memory footprint is far smaller. I use a bitwise operation to gain a little more speed.

```
selectHamInt = 
  Compile[{{ll, _Integer, 
     1}, {val, _Integer}, {n, _Integer}, {ilen, _Integer}},
   Select[
    ll, (Apply[Plus, Sign[IntegerDigits[BitXor[#, val], 4, ilen]]] > 
       n) &], CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> 
      True}, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", CompilationTarget -> "C"];

ilen = 13;
rest = Range[0, 4^ilen - 1];
Length[rest]

j = 0;
Timing[
 res = Reap[recent = rest[[1]];
     rest = Rest@rest;
     Sow[recent];
     While[ListQ[rest] && rest =!= {},
      ok = selectHamInt[rest, recent, 5, ilen];
      If[ok=!={},
        Sow[recent = First[ok]];
        rest = Rest[ok]];
      ];
     ][[2, 1]];]
Length[res]

(* Out[43]= {8831.97, Null} *)

Length[res]                                                            

(* Out[44]= 4096 *)
```

So it takes 2.5 hours to run to completion.

--- end edit ---

Comment: Thanks for this response, I'll try in the morrow!

Answer (score 6):

Correct me if I'm wrong, you're looking for 10,000 lists each with length 13, every element can be `{1,2,3,4}` and each list has at least 5 hamming distances from the rest.

It's probably beyond the realm of this community to use other languages but since it's substantially faster, I decide to write this answer with `Julia` (from version 12.1 can be run inside Mathematica, so not much deviation).

### Code

```
# package to save the result in CSV
using DelimitedFiles

# raise error to save the result when Ctrl+c is pressed during the calculation
Base.exit_on_sigint(false)
const file_path = "C:\\FileName.csv"

@inbounds function simulation(n::Int64 = 4000,similarity::Int64 = 5,column_size::Int64 = 13)::Matrix{Int8}

    # hamming_distance(left,right::Vector{Int8}) = count(==(1),left .!= right)
    
    function above_hamming_distance(left,right::Vector{Int8},n::Int64)::Bool
        unique_elements = 0
        for i in 1:length(left)
            
            if left[i] != right[i]
                unique_elements+=1
            end
            if unique_elements >= n
                return true
            end
        end
        false
    end
    
    # version 1
    # check_choice(filtered_choices,result::Vector{Int8})=all(>=(similarity),count.(==(1),eachrow(result'.!=filtered_choices)))

    # version 2
    # check a solution to be valid by compareing to the give solution
    function check_choice(filtered_choices,result::Vector{Int8})::Bool
        
        for choice in eachrow(filtered_choices)
            
            if !above_hamming_distance(choice,result,similarity)
                return false
            end
            
        end
        true
    end

    # preallocating space
    choices = zeros(Int8,n,column_size)

    # add random choice to the solutions
    all_values=Int8(1):Int8(4)
    choices[1,:]=rand(all_values,column_size)
    counter::Int64=2

    function generate_choice(choices::Matrix{Int8},counter::Int64)
        
        result=rand(all_values,column_size)

        # if solution is valid by comparing to previous similar solutions, add to the solutions
        if check_choice(view(choices,1:counter-1,:),result)
            choices[counter,:]=result
            counter +=1
        end
        
        counter
    end

    try
        @time while counter <= n
            counter = generate_choice(choices,counter)
            # println(counter)
        end
    catch e
        writedlm( file_path,  choices[1:counter-1,:], ',')
    end

    choices
end

# save the result
writedlm( file_path,  simulation(4000), ',')
```

### Speed

```
1.061022 seconds (78.39 k allocations: 4.784 MiB)
```

It produces `4,000` items in around `1.0` seconds!

To test the result we can open the `CSV` in Mathematica and check:

```
data = Import["C:\\FileName.csv", "Data"];
result1 = Outer[HammingDistance, data, data, 1];

Count[MemberQ[#, 1 | 2 | 3 | 4] & /@ result1, True]
(* Out: 0 *)

DuplicateFreeQ[data]
(* Out: True *)
```

I'm not an expert in Julia and tried to limit the computation (using vectorized operation, preallocating) or memory usage (using `view`), but I'm sure with so many hacks and macros, it could be improved.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Reap and Sow and a loop over possible pairs. Here is a small example:

```
all = Tuples[Range[2], 3];
res = Reap[
    Do[If[HammingDistance[all[[i]], all[[j]]] > 2, 
       Sow[{all[[i]], all[[j]]}]], {i, Length[all]}, {j, 1, i - 1}];
    ][[2]];

res
```

[image]